# Changing a value type when it is passed to a method in C#

Tags: c#, methods, parameter-passing, value-type

Basic manuals on C# state that to change a value type when passed to another method you must use the `out` or `ref` keywords, etc.

For example:

```
int Loop(int counter)
{
   return(++counter);
}

void ClickIt ()
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int c1 = 0; c1 < 10; c1++) 
    {
        count = Loop(count);
        Console.Writeline(count);
    }
}
```

Here, `ClickIt` outputs the following result: `1, 2, 3, 4, ... 10`

In the example, `count` (a value type), which is being passed from the method `ClickIt` to the method `Loop` *without* `out` or `ref`, is being changed in `Loop`. And `Loop` then returns `count` to the calling method `ClickIt` which picks up the change to `count`.

So, my question is: When is a value type, when passed as an argument to another method, required to use `out` or `ref` so that the value can be changed?

Comment: Objects are passed by ref, for struct and basic data types, it's by val unless out or ref is specified

Comment: The changes are *not* passed back via the parameter of `Loop`. The changes are written into your `count` variable because you explicitly assign the return value of `Loop`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have an incorrect understanding of the meaning of "ref", and you are also mixing up values and variables.  These are common mistakes.

Let's go back to basics.

A *variable* is a *storage location* which can contain a *value*.

Let's simplify your program:

```
int M(int x)
{
    x++;
    return x;
}
void N()
{
    int y = 0;
    y = M(y);
}
```

If N is called, what happens?

Imagine a variable is a drawer that can contain a sheet of paper.  We make a drawer and label it y. In y we put a piece of paper that says "0".  Now we call M(y). What happens?

We make a new drawer labeled "x" and we make a *photocopy* of the piece of paper in "y". We put the copy in drawer x. y contains a piece of paper that says 0, and x contains a different piece of paper that also contains 0.

Now in M we increment x. What happens?  We make a new piece of paper that says 1, throw away the old one, and put the new one in drawer x.

Now we make a photocopy of the value in x, so we have another piece of paper that says 1.  When M returns we put that piece of paper into y and throw away the 0 that is already in there.

Did M modify y?  No. M only modified x.  N modified y, twice. Once when y was created, and once after M returned.

Notice that we made *two copies*. First, we made a copy of y on the way in to M and copied it to x, and then we made a copy of x on the way out and copied it to y.

Now suppose we have

```
void P(ref int b)
{
   b++;
}
void Q()
{
    int c = 0;
    P(ref c);
}
```

We run Q. What happens? We make a drawer called c and put a piece of paper in it that says "0".  What happens when we call P?  Something different. This time we make a drawer called b and put a piece of paper in it that says "don't use this drawer! Every time you try to use this drawer, use c instead!"  That is, b *refers its behaviour to c*.

Now P tries to increment b. It tries to get a value out of b, but discovers that b says no, use c. So it looks in c, finds 0, makes a new piece of paper that says 1, replaces the contents of b -- no, wait, we need to replace the contents of c -- with 1, and returns.  So c is updated to 1.

Does it make sense why these two things are different?  The first is called **copy in, copy out** because we make a photocopy of y on the way in to M, and a copy of x on the way out.  The second is called **by reference** because b refers its behaviour to c; no values are copied.

Answer (score 3):

In your sample you actually do not modify passed count variable. 
When it's passed, a copy inside a Loop function scope is being created. Then modification done, you return in back and set to your count variable.

Actually, the purpose of:

1. ref - is that variable should be already initialized before passing into function. And copy is not created inside. You modify passed variable directly. As result - you don't need to return modified value and set it back to your variable.
2. out - it does not require passed variable to be initialized before passing into your function. But it actually MUST be initialized inside that function.

Hope that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Long comment...
Your code could be confusing - make sure to separate result of function from parameter:

```
void ClickIt ()
{
    int count =0;
    for (int c1 =0; c1 < 10; c1++) 
    {
        var resultCount = Loop(count);
        Console.Writeline("Result:{0}, count:{1}", resultCount, count);
    }
}
```

Answer (opinion based) - you should almost never use `out`/`ref` - it is much harder to reason about than return values. Such functions also are hard to use in LINQ/lambda expression due to need of arguments to be variables.

Common case when it somewhat acceptable is when function returns more than one result (like `TryParse`), but consider if some other return type (i.e. nullable `int?`) would work too.